Posit Connect deploy non R/Python API
I was wondering if its possible to host a non R/Python API on a Posit Connect server.
This might be a Javascript API/Website or as in this case a Go API.
For testing I have a simple Go API like this:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)

func echoHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    input := r.URL.Query().Get("input")
    goVersion := runtime.Version()
    response := fmt.Sprintf("Input: %s, Go Version: %s", input, goVersion)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, response)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echoHandler)
    fmt.Println("Server is running on port 8080...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}


which I can build and run like this go build . (as I work from a dir tester-api, this is the name of the executable as well), run it with ./tester-api and then query it locally with curl localhost:8080/echo?input=123, where I receive the result Input: 123, Go Version: go1.22.5 - so all good so far!
I want to host this API on a Posit Connect server alongside other R/Python APIs.
There seems to be no direct way, but I didn't want to give up just yet.
One possible (but arguable very hacky) solution is to use an R/Python API and forward requests to a local version of the Go API (eg the Go API is started by the R API on a specific port and each incoming request to the R API is then forwarded to the Go API running on localhost).
I have also looked into manifests from rsconnect but didn't see anything that looked like I might be able to do it this way.
Any other ideas or solutions?
